# binary data socket over android and java

Tags: java, android, binary-data

I am using this code to get my image from facebook server.

```
String imageURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?type=large";                               
InputStream inputStream = new URL(imageURL).openConnection().getInputStream();
DataInputStream dataStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[4096];
ByteArrayOutputStream dataHolder = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int n;

while ( (n=dataStream.read(dataBuffer))!=-1 ){
  dataHolder.write(dataBuffer, 0, n);
}
```

and using the same way to get my image from my server:

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputSTream("/image.jpg");
DataOutputStream dataStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutpustStream());
byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[4096];
int n;

while ( (n=inpuStream.read(dataBuffer))!=-1 ){
  dataStream.write(dataBuffer, 0, n);
}//get -1 perfectly
```

and getting them on android app like this:

```
DataInputStream dataStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[4096];
ByteArrayOutputStream dataHolder = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int n;

while ( (n=dataStream.read(dataBuffer))!=-1 ){
  dataHolder.write(dataBuffer, 0, n);
}//-1 ??????????????
```

but the android app cant get the right file and it cant go out form while loop,exactly can not get -1 but yesterday I accidently got -1 from some changes I did,really can not understand why I can not get -1 in my android app however I can get it from the servers while loop

Comment: all you need is the image from the server right?

Comment: Your question is not really clear. What is the problem on Android? Do you get an endless loop, or does it finally simply block?

Comment: yes right image but the clent requests a lot of images one aftre the next if the client needs a lot of images.

Comment: @Paulo: I dont get an andeless loop and what I miss is the last block of bytes and n = -1 that means the stream ends on the nadroid app however I have another portion in my android app that gets images from facebook using the same mechanisme it works fine and gets n = -1

Comment: What is your *question?*

Answer (score 1):

You can directly convert the inputstream to a bitmap instead of reading bytes.

`Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);`

Comment: I know very well that there is a bug on java 1.4 and up that in the socket doesnt send FIN to the second side to say that data r done and transmition is done and in java 1.3 socket.getOutputStream().close() doent close out put stream but sends FIN to second side and this is what I want,but its a bug in java sockets and no fixing!!!! till java 6

Answer (score 0):

Here is just some glassball guessing: Did you close the stream on the server side?

Put a `dataStream.close();` after your writing loop.

Comment: but if I close stream all the socket is closed and its bad habit on java 1.4-6. please look to my comment here:\n I know very well that there is a bug on java 1.4 and up that in the socket doesnt send FIN to the second side to say that data r done and transmition is done and in java 1.3 socket.getOutputStream().close() doent close out put stream but sends FIN to second side and this is what I want,but its a bug in java sockets and no fixing!!!! till java 6

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand your problem yet. How should the receiver know that the image is finished if you don't close the stream?

Comment: look firend ,you know well that streams while reading bytes in java finishes once they get -1 number of bytes(look to java streams read docs) but I try this streams over network by sockets it doent gimme -1 number of reading bytes that means the sender stream is finished,also closng the stream that uses socket stream closes all the socket so its bad habit to close the stream and the only solution is to get -1 of reading bytes to finish reading and end loop